# Register new account via REST application

Tags: api, civicrm-home, user, rest

I'm trying to register a new user account to my CiviCRM site and also to create a contact in the CiviCRM system for him. I want to do that via the REST API call application that I'm writing in python.
After some investigations, I saw that I need to send the request to Drupal system and not to The CiviCRM module.

Can anyone tell me how can I do that REST API call?

My CiviCRM is on Bitnami with AWS instance, with Drupal.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Since that's straight drupal I would try the [drupal docs](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/rest/1-getting-started-rest-configuration-rest-request-fundamentals) and if you're still stuck you might get more responses at https://drupal.stackexchange.com.

Another thing you could try but I don't know if it will work is to use civi's api Profile.submit. If you have a profile at admin - customize - profiles which is configured for Drupal User Registration and allows creating users, you might be able to pass in the right parameters to include the account name/email to create the account.

Answer (score 0):

This API doesn't exist in CiviCRM but if you want to stick with CiviCRM API (which is better if you want to keep it CMS agnostic), you could create a new CiviCRM API which is not too complex if you are a developer.

With civix installed, it would require to :

1. create an extension `civix generate:module thenewextension
2. go in `thenewextension` and generate the api `civix generate:api MyEntity myaction`
3. a new file should be created in `api/v3/MyEntity/myaction.php`
4. in the php, call the CMS agnostic function `$ufID = CRM_Core_BAO_CMSUser::create($params, $mail);` and add the logic you want
5. activate the extension
6. you should be able to see your api and test it in `https://www.mysite.com/civicrm/api

To call the API using REST, you need to call the url with the correct parameters (or more likely use a python library that will do much of the work for you) :
`https://www.mysite.com/sites/all/mdoules/civicrm/extern/rest.php?entity=MyEntity&action=myaction&api_key=(myAPIkey)&key=(mySiteKey)&json={“first_name":"xxx","last_name":"yyy","username":"zzz"}`

- `myAPIkey` must be created on a contact with the api permission in the database -> civicrm_contact table (or use a handy extension https://civicrm.org/fr/extensions/api-key)
- `mySiteKey` is in civicrm.settings.php
- `json` contains the parameters of your api call